# Creating fullchain.pem and privkey.pem with Easyrsa and ODK Central

Tags: certificate, openssl

The docs of my Docker-based server [getokd.org](https://docs.getodk.org/central-install-digital-ocean/#advanced-configuration-options) require:

> Generate appropriate fullchain.pem (-out) and privkey.pem (-keyout) files.

Using [easyrsa](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/blob/master/README.quickstart.md), I can generate the files for Entity `sg`

- ca.crt
- ca.key
- sg.crt, with `Certificate:    Data:        Version: 3 (0x2) .... BEGIN CERTIFICATE`
- sg.key, with `--- BEGIN ENCRYPTED`

I assume that `fullchain.pem` is the concatenation of `sg.crt` and `sg.key` (should I remove the `Certificate` section at the top?), and that `ca.key` probably is `privkey.pem`, but my attempts always led to error messages.

What is the correct way to produce the two required files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The CA private key should *never* be given to any other system – it should *only* be used for CA purposes and nothing else. (Anyone having the key could issue arbitrary certificates and completely compromise the CA.)

Instead, the `privkey.pem` file needs to contain the private key corresponding to the entity's *own* certificate, i.e. from "sg.key". Not all services are capable of loading encrypted keys (and they won't always be able to ask you for a passphrase) so you might need to decrypt the file using `openssl pkey`.

The `fullchain.pem` file needs to contain the entity's certificate itself, i.e. from "sg.crt", plus any intermediate issuer certificates. You don't have any intermediates, and the file doesn't need to include the root itself, so in your case it can be a direct copy of "sg.crt". (Most CAs will directly give you the full chain file anyway.)

Appending the root CA certificate (ca.crt) to the end of the chain won't hurt, but in most cases it will be useless, as clients which trust the CA will already have its certificate anyway. (One exception to this might be certain DANE/TLSA modes, but it's incredibly rare. Another exception is cross-signed roots but you don't have those.)

Yes, you can delete any "Certificate:" text that the CA tools might be adding. Software will only look at the delimited BEGIN/END blocks and will usually ignore any surrounding text.

Comment: `openssl pkey -passin 'your_sg_password_from_easyrsa' -in sg.key -out privkey.pem` That was the most important missing part.

Comment: Quoted here: https://forum.getodk.org/t/selfsign-certificate-with-latest-central/25466/8

Comment: Instead of deleting the password, one can also `easyrsa gen-req servername nopass`

Answer (score 1):

The file `fullchain.pem` is a file that contains a server certificate file and and an **intermediate certificate**.

`easyrsa` doesn't generate **intermediate certificates** as it is intended for exisitng certificate authorities.

The docs that you linked have this section **Using a Custom SSL Certificate** which provides information if you have obtained a certificate from certificate authority **other than Let's Encrypt.**

Meaning, if you purchased ssl certs from a different authority such as Godaddy, or Digicert, etc. This section of the docs tells where to place the files that you recieve from these vendors which includes the files `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem`.

Comment: >> easyrsa doesn't generate intermediate certificates? Strange, I found quite a few links how to do it. Did I understand these wrongly?

Comment: @DieterMenne: The most common way of using EasyRSA is that the user makes their own root CA and directly issues end-entity certs from it, like you are doing now. Although EasyRSA _can_ be used in a multiple tier setup (either as root or as intermediate), that's a bit less common in practice, and not something that happens automatically.